# Changing hand controller graphic in Google DayDream

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, daydream

Hello and I apologize first if this is a silly newbie question. Basically, is it possible to change the hand controller graphic in Google DayDream? Like instead of a menu, a picture of Homer Simpson. I haven't seen anything in the Google VR SDK that addresses accomplishing something like this.

Is it at all possible?

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Not possible with Google VR SDK? Seems like there ought to be some way to change that graphic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, you can change it. The controller Input is made up of a mesh that can be replaced by a custom one. Drill down the controllerPointer it has a child component called controller visual that has a ddcontroller mesh. You can swap it for a custom one